# How to make a callback from a Service to an Activity

Tags: java, android

Sorry for bugging you again, but I still can't find a way to make a callback from my activity to a service...

Found a similar question - [How to Define Callbacks in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android)

```
// The callback interface
interface MyCallback {
    void callbackCall();
}

// The class that takes the callback
class Worker {
   MyCallback callback;

   void onEvent() {
      callback.callbackCall();
   }
}

// Option 1:

class Callback implements MyCallback {
   void callback() {
      // callback code goes here
   }
}

worker.callback = new Callback();
```

yet not sure how to integrate that sample into my project.

Any suggestions or links to clear tutorials would be great!

Comment: How about binding service to your activity and just call its methods, so that you don't really need Observer pattern.

Comment: just please, how do I bind it to be able to call that method?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample below there is example of client code that you might put into your activity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That kind of callbacks (Observer pattern) that you are showing in your example won't work between a service and an activity. Use observer patter when, from class A, you **created the instance** of class B and want to send callbacks from B to A.

With regards to the services and activities, things are completely different. AFAICT, if you want to callback your `Activity` from a `Service`, the best method to achieve this is to use [`ResultReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html). There are a lot of interesting things about `ResultReceiver`:

- Its constructor receives a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) (that you must create inside the activity), which will allow you to change UI from the service.
- It implements [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) thus you can put a reference of your `ResultReceiver` in the `Intent` extras that you used to start the service.
- Its `onReceive` method has a result code integer which allows you to generate different kind of callbacks (this is like if your callback interface had many methods). Also, it receives a [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) which you can use to put all result data.

On the other hand, if you want to do a *callback* (not sure if that is correct term in this case), from your `Activity` to your `Service`, I guess you will have to send a Broadcast message or something like that.

Comment: great, thanks! maybe a short snippet would be great, if possible. :)

Comment: I am in doubt now. You want to callback the Acitivity or the Service?

Comment: I want to call back a service from an activity.

Comment: try this , something similar to above answer but with example :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/6371332/501483