# How to get access to view from onPrepared?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a three class: MainActivity, MyService, MyPlayer.
MainActivity start service, which start AsyncTask and start MyPlayer (MediaPlayer) play method. But problem that I try to start a radio stream, which are loading for a while(5-10 sec), I want to inform listener that stream loading and infrom when stream loaded (public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) method) in a MainActivity's view, but have an error "can't create handler inside thread". How do I can access to mainactivity's view and context (for toast messages). My code chains:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
 startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

public class MyService extends Service 
player = new MyPlayer(ctx);
AsyncTask
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
             player.play();

public class MyPlayer implements OnPreparedListener, OnCompletionListener 
@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
```

How to get access to MainActivity's view and context from onPrepared?

Answer (score 0):

This is complex. I think the right approach to your question is here:

[How to make a callback from a Service to an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283229/how-to-make-a-callback-from-a-service-to-an-activity)

But you may be just fine sending a broadcast:

http://androidexperinz.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/communication-between-service-and-activity-part-1/

Depends on the complexity and timing of the interaction.