# Android: Close activity when new is started?

Tags: java, android

I am making a music player and I have a list with all the music. When you click on one it opens a new activity and plays the song, but if I go back to the list and choose another song it doesnt stop the first.
How do I make it stop the music or close the first activity when I play a new song?

I have tried setting the launchMode to "singleTask" but that didnt work ..

Comment: How are you starting the music track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `finish()` your Music playing activity in the `onStop()`-method. This will close the Activity and open a new one after you choose a new song to play.

A better way of doing this (since you're creating a multimedia player) would be to play the music in a Service (not in an Activity) and simply use the "player"-activity or the "playlist"-activity to change the played sound.

This way, the user can leave your app and still listen to his music. Also, it enables him to browser his music for a new track while listen to something else.

---

To communicate with your Service, you'll need to "bind" it. In your case, I'd suggest a `Binder` to do so. Read the ["Bound Service"-article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) from the docs for more information/examples.

Comment: How do I get the music duration to make a seekbar if the music is playing in a Service?

Comment: You can use messaging to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369287/accessing-ui-thread-handler-from-a-service

Comment: How do I pause and resume the music in a Service?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: A nice tutorial can be found here: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-ii

Comment: I get a lot of errors with that code, one of them: android.os.BinderNative does'nt exist. Is that tutorial working with android 2.2 and up?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't tested it. I updated my post, have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that.