# Implementing callback from Service to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, android-service

I have been playing with `Service`, but I cannot get them to run like I need. I need to call the `Service` functions from the `Activity`, and I use this

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LocalService getService() {
        return LocalService.this;
    }
}
```

But how do I callback the Activity once a long network operation is done?

I want to show a spinner on the action bar while the service does something, and when it finishes to hide it. I also need it to persist on all different activities that have the same action bar.

Also, `ServiceConnection` is an asynchronous callback, so how do I bind to the service, wait for the callback *and then* change from case to case which function of the service to call?

Comment: Related: [Accessing UI thread handler from a Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369287/accessing-ui-thread-handler-from-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

well , the call to the service's function is synchrounous , but the implementation of the function on the service can be asynchrounous (for example , using asyncTask ) and when the result is finished , you can either send an intent , or call a listener that was stored for the call .