# RunOnUiThread in DreamService?

Tags: android, dreamservice

I have a DreamService and I want to begin updating some UI stuff once a background thread completes (I'm raising an event to trigger this). 
In the main version of my app I just use RunOnUiThread to start the UI updates from the event but dreamService isn't descended from Activity so no such method.
Weirdly, I'm not getting errors, I just get a blank screen.
In my catlog I see warnings from my UI code but they are "empty" (no message, I just see "W at com.my.app" 3 times, different lines of code)

I think the most likely reason is triggering UI changes from an event raised in a thread so how can I do UI thread updates in a Dreamservice?

Comment: create a handler from the ui thread (like in onCreate) and post on it.

Comment: OK, I tried adding a handler and sending the message from the event trigger- now in Catlog I get the warning about only the thread that created it can touch views, so I think you're along the right lines, I'll keep playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to njzk2 for pointing me in the right direction. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369287/accessing-ui-thread-handler-from-a-service), specifically:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(something_to_run_on_main_thread);
```