# Using service to show up toasts

Tags: java, android, service, toast

I am quite busy with a new application. However I created a service which calls a method like this:

```
MessageProcessor mp = new MessageProcessing(MessageService.this);
wa.setNewMessageBind(mp);
```

However since it's added into a service instead of an Activity this error shows up:

```
nl.giovanniterlingen.whatsapp.MessageService cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

And yes, I searched a lot on the internet, but still I couldn't find an answer that fits my need. Here is the MessageProcessing source:

```
((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            msg.getFrom() + "(" + msg.getGroupId() + "): "
                                    + msg.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
```

When I replace the toast with `system.out` like this:

```
System.out.println(msg.getFrom() + "(" + msg.getGroupId()
                    + "): " + msg.getText());
```

Then it's working fine, but I want a toast so that's why I am asking.

For a more clearer view see my Github and the latest commits from 09-07-2015

https://github.com/gi097/WhatsApi-Android

Comment: Give me the whole class or just the class name

Comment: Keeps on  `Toast...` and remove everything else.

Comment: @Sheychan see MessageService.java and MessageProcessing.java

Comment: Well, you can't cast a Service to a Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Your msg here" + msg.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Even better! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: actually the same i've written. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast your **MessageService**, which extends **Service**, to a **Activity**.

You need to access your UiThread from a Service. Check this question, maybe it'll help you: [Accessing UI thread handler from a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369287/accessing-ui-thread-handler-from-a-service)

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.post(something_to_run_on_main_thread);
```

Answer (score -1):

`private Toast myToast;`       // Declare as Field

`myToast  = Toast.makeText(this, "DummyMessage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`    // In onCreate(Bundle b)

```
myToast.setText("yourActualMessage");    // set msg Inside service or whatever

myToast.show();                    // Display in service or anywhere you want
```