# Android can I use Looper for recursive callback HTTP service requests?

Tags: android, android-service, android-looper

In our Android app, we're using 3rd party vendor for Chat service. We need to create session for the user, then login to use the service and then have to fetch messages. All are separate HTTP requests which needs to be called inside one's success callback. So how can I make it, like below.

```
   ExternalService.createSession(param1, param2, new Callback<Session>() {

        void onSuccess(Session session) {
             session.login(new Callback<User> {


             void onSuccess(User user) {

                 user.getMessages(new Callback<List<Messages>> {

                      void onSuccess(List<Messages> messages) {
                         // This is original place where everything is success
                      }

                      void onError(Error error) {


                      }

                 } 
             }

             void onError(Error error) {


             }
        }

        void onError(Error error) {

        }

   });
```

If I run in the `Activity`, it is working fine no issues. How to do it in a `Service` ? Because in `Service` also I have problem running `AsyncTask`, throwing error **`"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"`**. `Service` exits after calling the `AsyncTask` and reaching end of `handleAction` block.(I understand, that is the behaviour `Service`). But how can I achieve without using `Looper` ? Or if there is no other way to do without using `Looper`, how can I stop it after accomplishing what I need ? What is the best approach to do this ?

Comment: This post might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369287/accessing-ui-thread-handler-from-a-service

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's no UI interactions (because you're running the code from a Service), just convert the `AsyncTask` to a `Runnable` and wrap a `Thread` around it:

```
new Thread(new Runnable {

  @Override
  void run() {
      // whatever happens in AsyncTask.doInBackground goes in here
  }

}).start();
```

Comment: I think this would be the correct answer, but @adelphus let me check and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)) to do background operations like this.

It basically executes work requests passed to it sequentially in a dedicated background thread.

In the `onHandleIntent()` method, you can define your sequence of API calls sequentially without even needing callbacks making the code more readable (if your library supports blocking calls of course).

Something like:

`//This is just pseudocode to give an idea of how this would work
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
   Session session = createSession();
   User user = session.login();
   List<Messages> messages = user.getMessages();
}`

You can do this because everything that happens in the `onHandleIntent()` method happens in a background thread and thus these operations will not block the UI.

You can look at the official [IntentService tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) for example usage.

One thing to note is that you cannot manipulate UI directly through this service. To communicate back to the Activity, you can use the [LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) method. This is also explained in the tutorial.

Comment: But what if suppose the library don't support blocking calls ?

Comment: then you can use the callback methods as you normally would inside ```onHandleIntent```. It's just an option that makes things easier if present is all.